# Gradle offline sync issue

Tags: android, gradle, offline

I'm facing an issue using gradle in offline mode:
I'm running my project fine when offline is uncheked, then, I need to work offline (because I'm taking the train), and, without touching any gradle file, this error is thrown:

```
 > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
 Required by:
     project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1
     project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:15.0.1
     project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:15.0.1
  > No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
```

Why this dependency was not cached during the last online sync? how can I do to be able to build this project without any internet connection?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Mariusz, please check my answer below:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59121559/6103242

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be related to conflicting versions of `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement` dependency implicitly required by more than one higher-level dependencies came from your *build.gradle*.

The steps below describe how to diagnose the same issue but with `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier` (used in examples below) dependency.

"app" is used as an example, so **replace** the *app* with actual name of your app_module.

**Prerequisites** (initial problematic case):

My *build.gradle* has the following:

```
...
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
...
```

running Gradle sync works fine when *Offline work* is unselected. But as soon as I turn ON *Offline work*, the following error pops up during gradle sync:

```
:app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
...
```

**Steps** to diagnose:

1. Print all the places where *play-services-ads-identifier* dependency is referenced from

```sh
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration releaseRuntimeClasspath --dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier"
```

In my case among all of the output I see the following lines:

```
...
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:17.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0 (requested com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:[17.0.0])
|    |
...
...
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 17.0.0
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1
     +--- releaseRuntimeClasspath
...
```

The line

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 17.0.0
```

means that there was a conflict and the version of *play-services-ads-identifier* was resolved to 17.0.0 while initially 15.0.1 was requested.

2. The next and most **important** things to look at are where *play-services-ads-identifier* was referenced from. This is specified in the output the next line after the name of the dependency, in my specific case those sources are

   1. com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:17.0.0
   2. com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1

Since I know that those 2 dependencies are my top-level dependencies (i. e. are explicitly specified in *build.gradle*). Now I have the following options to solve the problem.

**Solution 1**
I can avoid versions conflict e. g. by upgrading
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0` in *build.gradle* in the *app* module. Doing this allows Gradle to sync successfully when **Offline work** is selected.

**Solution 2**
Keep dependency but exclude conflicting modules. I. e. change

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

to

```
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-ads-identifier'
}
```

After doing this, I'll face few more sync errors since few more underlaying dependencies have conflicts. As a result, I'll end up with the following:

```
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-ads-identifier'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
}
```

This makes Gradle **work offline** as well.

*NOTE*:
In your case the source dependencies that cause the conflict may be found deeper in a tree-like output of the *dependencyInsight* command showed above.

---

Environment I'm using:
Android Studio v3.5.2 on macOS, Gradle plugin v3.5.2, Gradle v5.6.4